# Accessibility issue on mouse hovering using NVDA tool

Tags: html, nvda

I have been using NVDA tool to identify accessibility issues in HTML page. I have been receiving an issue where the tool tip is not readable.

```html
<span class="icon-interface-question-mark" title="Click for Info" (click)="showAdditionalInfo()">
```

I had added title attribute to fix the issue. But it is not working. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If that's your only code for the tooltip, the keyboard focus will not move to it.  You'd need `tabindex="0"` to allow a keyboard user to tab to it.

But that would be a bad design too because non-interactive elements should not be tab stops.

Take a look at the (not yet complete) [tooltip design](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#tooltip) pattern on "WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1".

The tooltip should be associated with the input field and should be displayed when the input field receives focus.  The tooltip itself should not receive focus.